# Need to implement a fully functional SWI-Prolog Interpreter or GNU Prolog running on top of Python

Tags: python, prolog, ffi

I am currently working on a project for my Logic Programming class in which we need to be able to parse natural human language using Prolog. We plan to use CMU-Sphinx (through a Python module "pocketsphinx") as a voice to text converter. Broken down, this would look like the user saying "Hey what time is it". Then Sphinx will convert this to a string stream, then Python will save this into a variable userinput.

Then, we want to pass this text to a Prolog interpreter, where we already consulted file "dictionary.pl" which would have defined a predicate "parse". Therefore, the text we would send from Python to the underlying Prolog interpreter would look like "parse(userinput)."

Then, for now, let's say Prolog has unified this query using a predicate for "time", it would return the phrase "time = 12:40AM" to Python, which in term, will send this to CMU-Sphinx, which will read this out.

Now, because of the nature of our project, we need to do the vast majority of the definitions in the file "dictionary.pl". So as much as we would love to just do this in Python and save ourselves the headache, we cannot get around the requirements of using Prolog. Because of this, we need Python to send user input to a running Prolog interpreter.

Thus far, we have attempted a few things. the pyswip module is okay, but because at its core, it does not actually run Prolog.

Basically, we need a full on implementation of SWI Prolog or GNU Prolog running below our Python script, and to be able to pipe user inputs into the current running instance of Prolog (without creating new instances)

Thus far, we have experimented with the Python subprocess library and came up with something like this:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT
print("Launching gprolog process")
prologengine=Popen(["gprolog", "dictionary.pl"], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)

while True:
    line = raw_input(">")
    prologengine.stdin.write(line+'\n')
    result = []
    while True:
        if prologengine.poll() is not None:
            print('prologengine has terminated.')
            exit()
        line = prologengine.stdout.readline().rstrip()
        if line == '[end]':
            break
        result.append(line)
    print('result')
    print('\n'.join(result))
```

However, this does not seem to create the prolog engine that can be be interacted with as intended.

Also, we have tried to do an os call to swipl and gprolog in the IPython interpreter. It seems we can definitely turn on the instance of the Prolog interpreter running on top of IPython. However, we have no way to do the "python" stuff we need to do without exiting the Prolog interpreter and going back to IPython.

Any suggestions as to how we can create a fully operation REPL object that we can interact with through Python? (e.g. get a user input in Python, send that as a query to Python, at unification, send that back to Python and print it until we have no more unifications)

I know this is very specific, but this is the only way we could see using CMU Sphinx in conjunction with Prolog.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Are pipes the only option? Using sockets and possibly HTTP may be easier and more portable.

Comment: Are you really asking how to implement a Prolog "on top of" (in?) Python, or just how to use a Prolog database, using an existing Prolog implementation, and query it from Python?

Comment: Adding to the suggestions by @mat, you can call C from Python, and SWI-Prolog from C, but this is definitely much more work than communication over HTTP for example.

Comment: @mat That sounds like a potential solution. How would I go about setting up the input/output ports for the Prolog Interpreter? (If you aren't aware, Prolog is basically pure recursion and first order predicate calculus turned into a language. So there is very limited support for anything technological innovation that happened after 1990)

Comment: @Boris It is necessary to implement this because I need an actual Prolog Interpreter rather than a Prolog "emulator."

Comment: @Boris It is necessary to implement this because I need an actual Prolog Interpreter rather than an "emulator." Specifically, I can do the following in Python: `from pyswip import Prolog, Functor, Variable, Query
\n prolog = Prolog()\n prolog.consult("dictionary.pl")` The code for dictionary can be found [here](https://github.com/gilgameshskytrooper/LPFinalProject/blob/master/source/dictionary.pl). (8 Queens solution). However, if I do `prolog.query("template(X), solution(X)")` it states template is not defined, which means Prolog isn't an underlying process running below, but a "emulator"

Comment: Go ahead and read for example the [documentation of SWI-Prolog's HTTP package](http://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section(%27packages/http.html%27)). The easiest would be to start a Prolog web server, load the dictionary from it, and query it with an http client from Python.

Comment: Or, of course, you could implement a Prolog interpreter that integrates the algorithmic efficiency of Prolog with modern day networking capabilities.

Comment: @GilgameshSkytrooper: 1990 is the year SWI-Prolog started, and GNU Prolog started in 1996 under the name *Calypso*. Many constructs that are necessary to allow higher-order reasoning were standardized in [**Cor.2**](https://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/iso-prolog/#Cor.2) in 2012.

Comment: @Boris Thanks. We are currently messing around with it. We are having a weird problem where Prolog does not parse the input stream as a query, but I'm sure with a bit more digging around, we'll figure it out.